# If the supremum is finite, then the value is attained.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-programming, supremum-and-infimum, duality-theorems

In a linear programming proof we have the:

> $\sup\{c^Tx: Ax \le b\}$

This supremem can be $\infty$, or defined as $-\infty$, if there are no vectors x such that $Ax \le b$. But it is stated that should the supremum be finite, then there is one vector that attains $x_0$ such that $c^Tx_0=\sup\{c^Tx: Ax \le b\}$. Why is this?

Comment: Because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space).

Comment: @vadim123 Thanks, but how does that help? In order for me to prove it I could only proceed if $\{x: Ax\le b\}$ was compact. Then I could use that there exist a sequence $\{x_k\}$ such that $c^Tx_k$ converged to the sup, and then find a subsequence to find $x_0$, But I do not know if that set is compact. But you mean it follows from completeness only?, can you please tell why?

Comment: Consider a sequence $\{x_k\}$ such that $c^Tx_k$ approaches this supremum.  With some care you can prove this is Cauchy, provided the sup is finite.

Comment: @vadim123 Ah I see, and you use that a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is ofcourse cauchy, and then you use $e^*=e/||c||$ and then cauchy-schwarz to get a cauchy for the sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$?